# Integrate RHEV 6.5 with OpenStack Juno

Tags: virtualization, redhat, openstack, openstack-juno

Can I use RHEV hypervisor to manage and deploy VMs in openstack environment? I have 4 node setup with 2 compute nodes which one connected to vCenter and Can I configure other node to connect to RHEV.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know RHEV integration with OpenStack is limited to networks, so no VM deployment is possible at the moment. You can use oVirt only for Neutron network management. You can import/create/delete networks on Neutron.

for more details see: 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Virtualization/3.4/html/Administration_Guide/chap-External_Providers.html